# Is Revelation 21:23 an allusion from Psalm 119:105 [118:105 LXX]?

Tags: revelation, psalms

The new heaven and earth described in Revelation has a city with no need of the light of either the sun or the moon:

> And the city has no need of sun or moon to shine on it, for the glory of God gives it light, and its lamp is the Lamb. (Revelation 21:23 ESV)
>
> καὶ ἡ πόλις οὐ χρείαν ἔχει τοῦ ἡλίου οὐδὲ τῆς σελήνης ἵνα φαίνωσιν αὐτῇ ἡ γὰρ δόξα τοῦ θεοῦ **ἐφώτισεν** αὐτήν καὶ ὁ **λύχνος** αὐτῆς τὸ ἀρνίον

A similar description of lamp and light is found in Psalm 119(118):

> Your word is a lamp to my feet an a light to my paths. [LXX 118:105] ([NET](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets/edition/24-ps-nets.pdf))
>
> **Λύχνος** τοῖς ποσίν μου ὁ λόγος σου
> καὶ **φῶς** ταῖς τρίβοις μου.

Both use the word Λύχνος (lamp) and light in Revelation is [φωτίζω](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G5461&t=KJV) whose root is [φῶς](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=G5457&t=KJV), the word used in the Psalm.

Is lamp in Revelation 21:23 an allusion to Psalm 119[118] intended to show the lamb is the word? In effect saying the lamb which is the lamp is the word which is the lamp?

Comment: @user33515 TY and welcome back

Comment: Thanks!  New job is much more time consuming!